How do we provide permission to use a figure that we hired a graphic designer to create in SciRep?
We hired a graphical designer who made us fancy visualisations for our paper.We signed the contract and paid him. He gave us the files and transferred copyrights to the university.
Now, at the production stage with Springer Nature, they asked for copyright from the owner (in English).
What shall we do now? The least bureaucratic option is preferred.

Is the issue that the signed copyright transfer from the designer to your university is in a different language?

Is SciRep Scientific Reports?

You need to work with the university to transfer copyright or an appropriate license to Springer and to assure them that you have the rights to use the figures. The university should have a legal office to handle this. The university is the owner so must be the one to handle the copyright transfer or license statement. The university should provide the new statement in English. If necessary you can provide a dual language version if you are in, say, France.
If Springer needs assurance that the university is the proper copyright holder and can transfer rights, have the university send a copy of the original transfer. If the original transfer is not in English then have a translation done and send Springer a copy of that translation and the original as well so that there is no misunderstanding. This last step might not even be necessary initially.
Note that you aren't the owner, nor can the creator help you since they have given copyright to the university. There is no way to avoid the university's participation since you are unlikely to be an "officer" of the university with authority in such things.
However, for open access, you may misunderstand what is being asked for. What Springer will need is a perpetual license to publish the work even in open access. It will be a license that is given, not the copyright itself. And the license extends rights to readers/users of the article, not just to Springer.

Scientific Reports is an open access only journal so it should not be necessary to sign over any copyright to the publisher.

@Anyon, then why are they asking for it? I'll add a bit.

Well, that is what I was hoping OP could clarify. I wonder if the usual form requires the authors to attest that they created all elements in the papers, and if not provide evidence (in English) that they have the right to publish elements created by others.

@Anyon: also for OpenAccess, the material needs to be properly licensed. IMHO it is a rather moot point whether we call this transfer (or new license), and whether it is done via Springer or by giving them the appropriate OA license. All this doesn't change the fact that without license, Springer cannot publish it, OA or not. (What is indeed not necessary is an excliusive license, a non-exclusive one is sufficient here)

Oh, and Springer has a legitimate interest in OP declaring to them that they do indeed have the right to grant such a license to them. Side note: depending on your legislation and employment status, university being owner of the (transferable) copyright is no different from OP drawing a figure: the transferable IP rights often are by default owned by the employer = university.


The least bureaucratic option is preferred.

There may be options:
In many jurisdictions, the transferable copyrights of a work produced by an employee are automatically owned by the employer, here the university.
If that is the case where you are, you may argue that this particular figure is really no different from any figures or text you produced: the copyright owner is in any case the university.
You may thus take the point of view that it is appropriate to involve university burocracy here to the same extent that you involve it for all other copyrighted parts of the paper: text, figures, tables...
This also means that you can license it just the same way you license all the other parts of the paper (assuming that you got the appropriate rights licensed from the creator - if not, legally speaking you need to contact them and ask for a correction/update of your license).
One level up the ladder of burocracy would be to let your PI (or whoever had the power to sign the contract with the designer) do the transfer. And then it is up to them to know whether they have the power to do so on their own, or whether they need to involve more administration.

If they tell you to do it, you're fine: burocratically speaking that is a task you're assigned to do. Burocratically speaking, it is up to your supervisor to know which tasks they are allowed to perform and delegate - none of your business.

If the procedure has been to fill in some form about the publication (this is required for publications in some institute where I have been), and you got it back signed and with the task to do the legwork of uploading stuff: I'd also take this as the assignment of the task to do as needed. Which includes the appropriate licensing for all materials including the fancy figure. (Advanced university burocracy asks for license matters in the "I want to publish"-form.)


